# Can "being attend to" be expressed as "in attendance"?

Tags: alternatives, false-friend

### EDIT: I structured my question around the misconceived assumption that "requests" could be "attended to", whereas what I meant translates to requests being processed.

In Portuguese, when someone or something is "being attended to" we say it is "em atendimento", which for English learners seems to be literally translated as "in attendance" (even Google Translate does the same). After some research, I now believe that's a false cognate and saying, for example, a request is "in attendance" isn't correct. Am I mistaken? Also, is there an adjective-like expression for "being attended to"? Something as close as possible to labels like "open requests", "cancelled requests", and not as big as "requests being attended to".

Comment: It is fortunate that your question got noticed by someone who knows Portuguese. In all honesty, I didn't understand the nature/sense of your question (because I don't know Portuguese).

Comment: I see... I thought that mentioning "being attended to" in relation to "requests" was enough because I thought it was a correct translation of what a meant. Hope the edit will make things clear for who stumbles across this thread in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To attend to someone is to take care of them. However, we don't use attend to mean customer service. To attend to someone or something means: to take care of something or something. I attend [take care of or handle] to business matters every day. **But it is most definitely not the translation of atender and atendimento in terms of business or requests for something.**

Google translate can't handle this term. It is a false cognate for the idea of: atendimento de  um cliente ou pedido which in English is expressed as: providing service to a client. If a request is em atendimiento, that means:
Your request is being processed. Requests are being processed. Your service request is being processed. We are processing your request.

**Pending requests** [em atendimento], not yet processed or handled.
**OR**: **Your request is being processed** or even serviced in some cases. We are servicing your request.

I speak Portuguese fluently and am very familiar with this issue.

Comment: Your question brings to mind the hazards of interpreting **puxe** (pronounced *push*) on Portuguese doors and telling a Portuguese pharmacist  that you are **constipado**.

Comment: Pu-shi, actually. Yes, funny.  And in Brazil, constipado is not used for colds. Only in Portugal.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this issue for me! I came across "servicing" when I was looking for how requests can be treated, and it's so strange to me. I'm not used to how it sounds, coming from a Portuguese background.

Comment: @RonaldSole OMG, a constipated nose is something to mull over... )))

Comment: @tenebris2020 Wait until you have an obstipated stomach!